# Do Bitcore APIs have daily limits?

Tags: transactions, api, transaction-verification, javascript, bitcore

I can't find online if the **bitcore API** (https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/packages/bitcore-node/docs/api-documentation.md) has daily limits for making requests, or if there is a need to pay some subscription once a certain threshold is exceeded.

> In a production environment developing a non-custodial wallet using
> these APIs, would you recommend it?

Comment: You seem to be linking to software that you can self-host. Why would you expect such software to have a rate limit if you are providing the service to yourself? Did you mean to ask about BitPay’s API instead?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure I properly understand your question.

If you’re asking about a self-hosted instance of the publicly available `Bitcore` software:
I suppose it’ll give you whatever data it can manage, and then the limits would be a function of the computer you run `Bitcore` on.

If you’re inquiring about BitPay’s API rate limits:
The only thing that I could find was that it says in BitPay’s API documentation under [“Setup and Testing > What Should You Test”](https://developer.bitpay.com/docs/testing#what-should-you-test): “Lastly, load testing our API is not advised or necessary and your application may be rate limited if load tests are detected.”

This sounds to me that their limits may be generous as long as they don’t perceive your use as excessive, but that you would need to reach out to BitPay to get more specific information.